# Makefile: How can I store and manipulate the current target/recipe/rule's value?

Tags: makefile

So I've got a makefile where I'm generating targets based on a list of directories, e.g.:

```
DIRLIST := dir1 dir2 dir3
```

I'm generating use case specific targets with prefixes added to the directory names, like so:

```
CLEANLIST := $(addprefix clean-,$(DIRLIST))
```

I'd then like to strip off the prefix in the target/recipe/rule, but I can't seem to read $@ into a variable:

```
$(CLEANLIST):
   @(eval TARGET=$@) #<-- this part results in TARGET being empty
   @(eval REALTARGET=$(TARGET:clean-%=%))
   #...do stuff...
```

Is there any way to populate a variable within the target/recipe/rule that has the directory name with the prefix stripped off?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Etan for pointing out that I messed up the syntax. It should be `$(eval ...)` instead of `@(eval ...)`. This is the most direct solution to my problem.

The relevant part of my recipe now looks like this:

```
$(CLEANLIST):
    $(eval REALTARGET=$(@:clean-%=%))
    #...derive some exported variable values from REALTARGET for use by secondary.mk...
    $(MAKE) -f secondary.mk clean
```

Comment: What is `@(eval TARGET=$@)` supposed to be? Is that supposed to be a call to the make `$(eval ...)` function? Is that supposed to be a sub-shell call `$$(eval ...)` (in a make recipe)? Also why are you trying to put it in another variable? Have you tried using `clean-%` as the target there and using `$*` instead?

Comment: @EtanReisner Oops, yes I should have used `$` instead of `@`. Thanks. Can you elaborate on how `clean-%` as a target would work? I tried defining a `clean-%:` target but it doesn't seem to trigger when I do `make clean-xyz`, unless I add `$(CLEANLIST)` to `.PHONY`, but then it just says "nothing to be done".

Comment: A target of `clean-%:` should match any `clean-xyz` target that you run and should do what you want (and set the stem variable `$*` to the part that matched the `%` wildcard. Do you have `clean-xyz` files in the directory?

Comment: No, they're meant to be recipes only (i.e. phony targets).

Comment: I realize that (and in which case they *should* be `.PHONY`) but having a file with the name accidentally (when they *aren't* `.PHONY`) will cause make to do nothing instead of running the correct recipe. Barring that (and barring other more-specific rules (like `$(CLEANLIST):`) the `clean-%` target/recipe should be used for `clean-xyz`.

Comment: Does is matter if the recipe name has forward slashes in it, or if another rule lists $(CLEANLIST) as a dependency?

Comment: It can matter if the target has a directory separator in it, yes. Because that changes the target. `clean-xyz` will not match `foo/clean-%` but will match `clean-%`. Other targets listing `$(CLEANLIST)` as a dependency shouldn't matter I don't think though.

Comment: I'm trying to match `clean-some/path/to/dir1` using `clean-%`.

Comment: Hm... yeah, that doesn't appear to work. That's unfortunate. You can use static pattern rules for this though. `$(CLEANLIST): clean-% :` and then use `$*` in the recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Etan for pointing out that I messed up the syntax. It should be `$(eval ...)` instead of `@(eval ...)`. This is the most direct solution to my problem.

The relevant part of my recipe now looks like this:

```
$(CLEANLIST):
    $(eval REALTARGET=$(@:clean-%=%))
    #...derive some exported variable values from REALTARGET for use by secondary.mk...
    $(MAKE) -f secondary.mk clean
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### Is there any way to populate a variable within the target/recipe/rule…

Sure. Gnu make has the ability to define [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html). You do that with a separate line including the target and the assignment, such as:

```
$(CLEANLIST): TARGET = $@
```

Of course, that would be silly since you could just use `$@` inside the recipe. But you might want to export `TARGET` to a submake. You can do that, too:

```
$(CLEANLIST): export TARGET = $@
```

> ### …that has the directory name with the prefix stripped off?

In a target-specific variable assignment, you can strip off the prefix in the usual way:

```
$(CLEANLIST): REALTARGET = $(@:clean-%=%))
```

### But:

What you can't (easily) do is set *shell* variables inside a recipe, because each line of a recipe is executed in a separate shell. For a shell assignment to be passed from one recipe command to the next, you either have to:

- put the assignment and the following command(s) in the same *logical* line. Either put the entire recipe in the same physical line, or compose the logical line using [backslash-newline continuation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html). In the latter case, remember that backslash-newline does not terminate a shell command; you'll need a semi-colon after the shell assignment.
- or use the [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) declaration.

See the make manual section on [Recipe Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the eval directives to set up target-dependent make variables (as opposed to shell variables) that will get passed down to sub-makefiles by a subsequent call to `$(MAKE) -f somefile sometarget` in my recipe.

Comment: @HunterZ: If you want make variables to be passed on to submakes, you need to `export` them. It is legal to put the `export` keyword in a target-specific assignment line; if you edit your question to specify your need, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I already figured out the export thing. It was just manipulating the target name to strip off the clean- prefix that was stumping me. Turns out it was a syntax error, per EtanReisner's comment. Thanks for your `$(@:clean-%=%))` suggestion - that was extremely helpful too!